# Check if value from array is equal to the type from Interface?

Tags: typescript

I've got an array

```
const arr = ["google", "yahoo"]
```

and interface

```
export interface Member {
  type: 'google';
  employed: true
}
```

How can I check if that array has the same type in Interface?

Comment: Why are you setting your interface properties to scalars rather than types?

Comment: Check when, at compile time? (then you'd need to write `const arr = ["google", "yahoo"] as const` so the compiler doesn't forget about `"google"`) Or at runtime? (then you'd need to write `const googleType = "google"; interface Member { type: typeof googleType; employed: true }` so that there's something at runtime to check).  Either way you'd need to refactor, or the answer is that you can't check.   Let me know which of those you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I basically need to write a function which will run only when certain variable is equal to the certain type from interface. Is that possible?

Comment: So you need this to happen at runtime.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgXd1N) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?